# What is the oldest "true" democracy?

Tags: voting, democracy, civil-rights

[According to PolitiFact, the United States is the oldest democracy.](https://www.politifact.com/wisconsin/statements/2016/jul/11/paul-ryan/paul-ryan-claims-us-oldest-democracy-world-he-righ/) However, the 26th Amendment, guaranteeing that all citizens 18 and over can vote, was only ratified in 1971 and the Voting Rights act was passed in 1965. Did any other countries have universal suffrage, protected by laws, before the United States?

Comment: I guess it would depend on what you define a true democracy as. For instance the united states is at best a representative democracy since people vote on others to make decisions for them. However when it comes to the office of the president the votes are not for the person running for office but for people to cast a vote for president. To make it even more confusing those people are not even always required to vote the same way as the people voted either and they could chose who they decide.

Comment: "true" is indeed a problematic qualifier. On many levels. As is 'universal suffrage'. Why not let 16yo vote? Like South Africa did in 1890, Law No. 5? How much 'direct democracy' is in the United States? How many felons are exempt from universal suffrage in the US? Looks like you have to narrow this down?

Comment: You really do need to specify what you mean.  "Suffrage for any legally adult human citizen capable of understanding the voting process" is probably what you mean. This isn't something that currently is the case in most countries, including the US.

Comment: @Obie2.0 What do you mean by capable of understanding the voting process? Not sure about the rest of the world but tests like that have been used to deny voting rights to people in the united states based on tests that are designed to not be passed.

Comment: @JoeW - What I am talking about are situations in which people with severe cognitive issues are disallowed from voting: for instance, people with severe Alzheimers. These sorts of incapacity laws are often highly broad, applied in a discriminatory manner, and do pick up people perfectly capable of voting, but the general idea is one that many people agree with. The list of criteria that I mentioned isn't the one I personally agree with, or even one that matches the US voting system, but my best guess at what the OP means.

Comment: @Obie2.0 who determines that though? In the south there was simple literacy tests (they where not that simple and designed to make people fail them) to keep certain people from voting.

Comment: [No "true" Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman) would even have to ask such a question.

Comment: @JoeW - Although cognitive incapacity laws do disenfranchise voters, they're *very* different in purpose, scope, and effect from poll tests aimed at black voters. If you're interested in how they're applied, it varies widely. In some states, judges have broad latitude and many capable voters with disabilities are denied the franchise. In other states, the only requirement is that voters be able to express a preference between candidates, designed to prevent absentee ballots filled in with the names of, say, people in comas.

Comment: And again, this isn't really my personal list of favorite qualifications, so I'm not too interested in its merits. I'd remove "adult," and "human" from that list and swap "citizen" for "long-term resident", and I'm only interested in the more narrow incapacity laws, like people who don't express a preference or even recognize a ballot and are just drawing on it. But it's what I expect most people using the term "universal suffrage" are thinking of.

Comment: To clarify a possible misconception: cognitive incapacity tests in the United States are essentially never applied at the time of voting. They refer to laws governing the decision by a judge to declare an individual unable to vote, typically during a case filed by someone seeking guardianship over an adult family member with cognitive disabilities. Thus, up to 1.5 million individuals, though probably significantly fewer, are thus possibly affected by such laws, a significant number of whom might be capable of voting in a broad sense.

Comment: I do not see why this is opinion-based. A (full) democracy is clearly defined: The elections need to be free, equal, direct, in secret and available for everyone. This are things you can look at and know if those requirements are fulfilled or not. Furthermore, the US aren't a (full) democracy, as the votes are neither direct, nor equal.

Comment: Well, it's that "equal" or possibly "free" that's the sticking point, isn't it? Nearly every country restricts the universe of possible voters from "anyone who could theoretically have a candidate preference." They might bar felons or prisoners from voting, like the US or Brazil. They might bar children, or children under a certain age. They might bar non-citizen residents, including territorial residents. They might bar people with major (or minor, or arbitrary) cognitive differences. Are these all not full democracies (maybe, but I don't think the question takes that view)?

Comment: Now that's nitpicking. IMO it should be pretty clear what's meant with "equal" and "free". Also you confused "free" (No force was used to influence the election) and "available for everyone". "Equal" = every vote has the same value. This is clearly observable in every voting system. "Available for everyone" = every mature human with a passport of the country can vote, if he want's to. If prisoners aren't allowed to vote, the state fails this point.

Comment: I thought this was a platform where clear facts are valued. I can't understand why a single "But how old do you have to be to vote" nitpicking argument would make a question where this is only a minor section "opinion-based".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90619/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-miep).

Comment: If this does reopen, which I don't think it should, it should be altered to say "Paul Ryan claimed..." PolitiFact does not make this claim itself.

Comment: I agree that this is POB, now that I think about it (and too broad, and unclear)

Comment: @Jontia I said PolitiFact because they said that Paul Ryan was telling the truth, as I wouldn’t necessarily trust him to be correct in this case.

Comment: The bump from 21 to 18 was in response to men 18 to 20 drafted for war when they can't even vote. The idea that *that* marks the usa's point of universal suffrage is conflating suffrage with society's ideas about maturity and adulthood. So you can push your date back to 1920, when women were granted the vote in the 19th amendment.

Comment: Is there a particular question that the page on "history of democracy" on Wikipedia didn't answer?

Answer (score 28):

Unclear on many levels and very US centric. "True democracy" is indeed a problematic qualifier. On many levels. As is 'universal suffrage'. Why not let 16 year olds vote? Like [South Africa did in 1890, Law No. 5? Or Iran with 15 (until 2007)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_age).

How much '[direct democracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_democracy)' is in the United States? How many felons are exempt from universal suffrage in the US?

1. Oldest parliament still existing: [Iceland 930 AD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Althing)
2. Oldest parliament in uninterrupted use: [Isle of Man 979](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tynwald)
3. First universal suffrage (women's vote) in a state still existing: [New Zealand 1893](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_democracy)
4. First universal suffrage ever: Pitcairn (of Mutiny on the Bounty fame (1789/1838) (Jad Adams: "Women and the Vote. A World History", Oxford University Press: Oxford, 2014, p 24)
5. First women candidates for country-wide elections Australia 1902, [Finland 1906 with (19) female members of parliaments in 1907](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suomen_%C3%A4%C3%A4nioikeuden_historia)
6. Oldest democracy still being one: [San Marino 380](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Marino) (With currently valid constitution-like documents from [16th century](https://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2011/aug/08/jon-huntsman/oldest-surviving-one-document-text/))

So is the USA the oldest democracy? According to the criteria [that Politifact made up:](https://www.politifact.com/wisconsin/statements/2016/jul/11/paul-ryan/paul-ryan-claims-us-oldest-democracy-world-he-righ/)

> Our democracy is imperfect and always evolving, but that’s the nature of democracy. The changes, for better or worse, reflect the will of the people.
>
> While the United States is not the first to include elements of democracy, it is the oldest existing nation with a constitutional government in which the people elect their own government and representatives.

That claim is "true": the US is the oldest US-style democracy. But this reasoning is constructed to exclude the other contenders and arguably difficult to project into the past, with slavery being one of the many stains on a thought-of 'clean' track record. The treatment of the ['Oldest Living Participatory Democracy on Earth'](https://ratical.org/many_worlds/6Nations/) being another.

Not even the official US foreign policy 'to foster democracy' is based on any consensual definition for 'what is a democracy?' ([Horowitz 2006](https://nationalinterest.org/article/the-struggle-for-democracy-880))

But according to the Economist Intelligence Report "Democracy Index 2017" ([PDF](http://pages.eiu.com/rs/753-RIQ-438/images/Democracy_Index_2017.pdf)), whihc analyses world government forms on a more universal level with objective criteria the same for all subjects investigated, the US isn't even in the club of 19 true, full democracies, *at all!*

> Almost one-half (49.3%) of the world’s population lives in a democracy of some sort, although only 4.5% reside in a “full democracy”, down from 8.9% in 2015 as a result of the US being demoted from a “full democracy” to a “flawed democracy” in 2016 (see Democracy Index 2017 by regime type, page 2). Around one-third of the world’s population lives under authoritarian rule, with a large share being in China.

On that list of 19 full democracies, in order: Norway, Iceland, Sweden, New Zealand, Denmark, Ireland, Canada, Australia, Finland, Switzerland, Netherlands, Luxemburg, Germany, United Kingdom, Austria, Mauritius, Malta, Uruguay, Spain,

> The US fell below the threshold for a “full democracy” in 2016 and is now rated as a “ awed democracy”. The main cause of the US regression was a serious decline in public trust in US institutions in 2016. This year the country’s overall score remained the same, and the US remains in 21st place in the global rankings.

---

> [The mutineers] took the ship to the uninhabited Pitcairn Island. Their descendants and occasional new arrivals continued to live there with, presumably, no form of government until a British captain stopped by in the HMS Fly in 1838 and the captain claimed the island for the Crown and provided them with ‘a few hasty regulations’.
>
> The islanders had urged Captain Russel Elliott to impose some kind of order as they were subject to marauding crews of whaling ships who would come ashore and threaten to rape Pitcairn women, which obliged the men to neglect their crops so they could act as protectors.They felt the solution was the protection of the British Crown for the ninety-nine natives. Elliott thought they could best be protected ‘by conferring the stamps of authority on their election of a magistrate or elder, to be periodically chosen from among themselves, and answerable for his proceedings to Her Majesty’s Government’.
>
> Captain Elliott’s feeling was to ‘least involve my own government’, and the best way to achieve this was to prescribe self-government for the islanders. He therefore said the island was to be governed by a magistrate
>
> > ‘to be elected by the free votes of every native born on the island, male or female, who shall have attained the age of eighteen years; or, of persons who have resided  five years on the island.’
>
> Thus suffrage was universal, and based on residency alone, making it an advanced form of democracy. It had come about at a time of crisis for the community, and had been granted by a superior power which had nothing to lose and some slight gain by doing so. While there is no reference to the reasons why women were equally enfranchised, it was doubtless because they were already playing some part in community life; and there had to be sufficient numbers to make the  fledgling democracy work.
>
> (Jad Adams, op cit)

Comment: I'd love some details on Pitcairn universal suffrage!

Comment: @gerrit Like that?

Comment: It would have been better off as a proper Q&A in its own right.  Q: _When was the earliest state/national level election with universal adult suffrage as we know it today?  How did it come about?_ A: _Pitcairn Islands, 1838-11-28._

Comment: Claims that the US democracy is flawed usually come from biased NGOs who's sole purpose of existence is to get more government grants. Not that the US democracy is perfect, but demoting it to a lower status because Trump was elected is a joke.

Comment: @JonathanReez - Well, he's weakened certain aspects of democracy in the United States. He's constantly sought to expand executive power, denigrated various branches of the federal government along with journalism meant to keep him in check, provided global cover for dictators, and increased the synergy between the executive branch and Congress.

Comment: @Obie2.0 Same can be said of Obama: so many EOs, his administration abused the IRS to hinder the Tea Party, he allowed spying on the campaign of a presidential candidate, and so on. The fact that it wasn't removed before 2016 but was in 2016 is a clear sign of bias.

Comment: @Sjoerd - That's a bit of an exaggeration. The executive orders, yes. But the "spying" was an FBI investigation of people in Trump's campaign that seemed to be based on legitimate grounds. As for the IRS behavior, that's not what people think: the IRS targeted political groups for extra scrutiny based on their names and descriptions: not just groups that had "Tea Party" in their names, but [also descriptors 
                                                                               like "Occupy" and "Green"](https://www.treasury.gov/tigta/auditreports/2017reports/201710054fr.pdf)

Comment: @Obie2.0 Should the USA expect another demotion now.  Never mind that apparently demotion is based solely on a survey of people and whether they're currently happy with their government or not.